# How can I parse a captcha image with data. and data changes

Tags: captcha

How to parse a captcha Image or get data from it? The data is part of image. The data changes with reloading. How to get the data on the image? can i do anything with data-url of image?

following is a example for captcha:
http://enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/ntes/CaptchaServlet?action=getNewCaptchaImg&t=1400870602238

Comment: Your link is not working :)

Answer (score 0):

Using OCR (Optical Character Recognition) is the first step. Below are 2 examples for such tools/APIs that can help you with that.

Try Tesseract.

> Tesseract is probably the most accurate open source OCR engine
>   available. Combined with the Leptonica Image Processing Library it can
>   read a wide variety of image formats and convert them to text in over
>   60 languages.

for more info check: https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

You can also try OCRopus

> OCRopus is an OCR system written in Python, NumPy, and SciPy focusing
>   on the use of large scale machine learning for addressing problems in
>   document analysis.

for more info check: https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

For detailed info with code smaple on how to do this, check Ben Boyter's article `Decoding CAPTCHA’s` at: http://www.boyter.org/decoding-captchas/